# Additional actions following spinner choice

Tags: java, android, spinner

My code is similar to the following:

```
package com.javasamples;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ArrayAdapterDemo2 extends Activity implements
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    TextView selection;
    String[] items = { "this", "is", "a", "really", 
            "really2", "really3",
            "really4", "really5", "silly", "list" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);

        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
                items);

        aa.setDropDownViewResource(
           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(aa);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
            long id) {
        selection.setText(items[position]);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        selection.setText("");
    }
}//class
```

In which place I need to implement something that after selection from spinner list, my program would for example change background picture. I was looking for something like setOnClickListener, but actually it works without it and in this case I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You have `onItemSelected()` in your code already, why not use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of an onClickListener for spinners is a onItemSelectedListener. It works basically the same way as an onClickListener - you set it by calling spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener, and you'll load intents into it as necessary.